# Markov Chain --- Being absorbed without reaching a specific state

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have a matrix 4-state Markov Chain that looks like this with state space $\{1,2,3,0\}$

\begin{pmatrix}
0.2 & 0.5 & 0.2 & 0.1\\
0.2 & 0.6 & 0.1& 0.1\\
0.2 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.2\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0.1\\
\end{pmatrix}
My question is: what is the probability that state 2 is never reached.

So my understanding is that this is equal to: probability of being abosrbed into state 0 without ever reaching state 2.

But I don't know how the standard $(I - Q)$ inverse method will work to avoid ever reaching state 2.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Try modifying the chain so that 2 is also an absorbing state.

Comment: As you never specified an initial condition, I assume you start in state 0, in which case you will never reach state 2, or any state other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

For $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ let
$$
\tau_i = \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \{X_n=2\mid X_0=i\} \right).
$$
Clearly $\tau_2$ is 1, and we have the system of linear equations
\begin{align}
\tau_1 &= \frac15\tau_1 + \frac12 + \frac 15\tau_3\\
\tau_3 &= \frac15\tau_1 + \frac3{10}+\frac3{10}\tau_3,
\end{align}
which has solution $(\tau_1,\tau_3) = \left(\frac{41}{52}, \frac{17}{26}\right)$. So the probability that state $2$ is never reached is
$$
1-\tau_i =
\begin{cases}
\frac{11}{52},& i=1\\
\frac9{26},& i=3.
\end{cases}
$$